# Laravel and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to plan out a project using angular and laravel. I am using various tools such as Gulp and I have a few questions.

I am happy to give up the ability to use the laravel 'views' folder and with it the blade templating. With the Public folder I have all the tools to be able to use Angular and Gulp. Within this folder I have all my Bower and Node dependencies.

The problem is How would I use Laravel to Route to the index.html file contained within an app folder within the public folder.

Comment: Why not just have one index file in the `views` folder?

Comment: Yeah I thought about this, and it's not up to me to make this decision but I have solved the problem now. Thanks

Comment: Ok. If you think it could help future visitors of this question, add an answer explaining how you solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have solved this issue.

Within the app/config folder there is a file called view.php.

Within this I have changed the path variable to look within the public/app/ directory.

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../../public/app'),
```

This will now be routable within the route.php file.

Answer (score 0):

While you can just redirect to angular index.html.

You can also just use index.blade.php to include

```
<angular-component></angular-component>
```

from your index.blade.php

I learned via using following

Laravel+Angular+Bootstrap https://github.com/silverbux/laravel-angular-admin

Laravel+Angular+Material https://github.com/jadjoubran/laravel5-angular-material-starter

Hope this help you understand how to utilize bootstrap & angular and speed up your develop by using starter.